# How to unlock Side Job King position?

Tags: dont-get-fired

I've been playing Don't Get Fired for weeks, regularly doing side jobs and have yet to unlock it. Is there any way to increase my chances of getting the Side Job King position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the wiki:](http://dontgetfired.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Positions)

> This one may be the most difficult hidden position to get, since this achievement may spawn at random after doing a part time job.
>   One would get it by doing a lot of part time jobs without getting promoted, reaching another hidden position (e.g. Evil) or leaving the game. (There's a false hypothesis which consists at staying for more than 20 seconds at the ad representing the part time job before closing it, but that would prevent 'No-ads' buyers to actually getting the position; more proofs would be needed for a more clean solution to this problem)
>
> You get no promotion chance increase, but every side job you complete, you get additional 200 money.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

No ads, just got promoted while going for evil. Just keep doing side jobs, and if you would rather have the +10% promotion chance and x2 pension then dont take side jobs!